# Streaming into <audio> element

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-streaming, mediastream

I would like to play audio from a web socket that sends packages of sound data of unknown total length. The playback should start as soon as the first package arrives and it should not be interrupted by new packages.

What I have done so far:

```
ws.onmessage = e => {
  const soundDataBase64 = JSON.parse(e.data);
  const bytes = window.atob(soundDataBase64);
  const arrayBuffer = new window.ArrayBuffer(bytes.length);
  const bufferView = new window.Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bufferView[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {"type": "audio/mp3"});
  const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const audio = document.createElement("audio");
  audio.src = objectURL;
  audio.controls = "controls";
  document.body.appendChild(audio);
};
```

However, to my knowledge, it is not possible to extend the size of `ArrayBuffer` and `Uint8Array`. I would have to create a new blob, object URL and assign it to the audio element. But I guess, this would interrupt the audio playback.

On the MDN page of [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), there is a hint to [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream), which looks promising. However, I am not quite sure how to write data onto a media stream and how to connect the media stream to an audio element.

Is it currently possible with JS to write something like pipe where I can input data on one end, which is then streamed to a consumer? How would seamless streaming be achieved in JS (preferably without a lot of micro management code)?

Comment: Use a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/) object.

Comment: @Green Does it have to be a WebSocket?  Why not just stream over HTTP, and then you could just plug in the URL to the audio element like normal?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a WebSocket. The background is that I want to test a WebSocket-based Web service and using Postman is currently not suitable for me (cannot save WebSocket requests, does not play back media). Hence, I'm just writing a simple HTML/JS example. Using `MediaSource` seems to work, I'll post a solution later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kaiido pointed out in the comments, I can use the [`MediaSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) object. After connecting a `MediaSource` object to an `<audio>` element in the DOM, I can add a `SourceBuffer` to an opened `MediaSource` object and then append `ArrayBuffer`s to the `SourceBuffer`.

Example:

```
const ws = new window.WebSocket(url);
ws.onmessage = _ => {
  console.log("Media source not ready yet... discard this package");
};

const mediaSource = new window.MediaSource();
const audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);

mediaSource.onsourceopen = _ => {
  const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("audio/mpeg"); // mpeg appears to not work in Firefox, unfortunately :(
  ws.onmessage = e => {
    const soundDataBase64 = JSON.parse(e.data);
    const bytes = window.atob(soundDataBase64);
    const arrayBuffer = new window.ArrayBuffer(bytes.length);
    const bufferView = new window.Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
      bufferView[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
  };
};
```

I tested this successfully in Google Chrome 94. Unfortunately, in Firefox 92, the MIME type `audio/mpeg` seems not working. There, I get the error `Uncaught DOMException: MediaSource.addSourceBuffer: Type not supported in MediaSource` and the warning `Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/mpeg`.

Comment: I dont know why this is not a famous answer, been looking exactly for that for hours!

Comment: Glad that it was helpful!